# Are questions about the nomenclature of geologic features on Mars off-topic in Space Exploration?

Tags: discussion, terminology

I'm curious about the decisions to name [these features](https://planetarynames.wr.usgs.gov/images/mc17_2014.pdf): [Dalu Cavus, Layl Cavus, Malam Cavus, Nat Cavus, Noc Cavus, Usiku Cavus, and Noctis Tholus](https://astrogeology.usgs.gov/news/nomenclature/names-approved-for-six-cavi-and-a-tholus-on-mars) in Noctis Labyrinthus. Why only some of the canyons, grabens and/or valleys are named. Is this off-topic for Space and should be in Astronomy SE?[image]

Comment: Regardless of topicality, the names in this case were selected by the IAU, which means it's probably better answered at Astronomy.

Comment: Right, makes sense.

Comment: Planetary science questions are considered on-topic for Space Exploration, but you probably will get a better answer from Astronomy.

Comment: @DrSheldon people's decisions on naming things may not really be representative of what "planetary science" means in the context of what is on-topic in Space SE.